# Powerpoint VBA: To execute from 2nd slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Good day,

I have got this code to modify the size and position of every shape on all slides, but would like the procedure to start ONLY from slide 2.

```
Sub SlideLoop()
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        ' check each shape on the slide
        ' is it an image or whatever you're looking for?
        For Each oSh In osld.Shapes
            With oSh
                If .Type = msoLinkedPicture _
                Or .Type = msoPicture Then

                ' position it to taste
                .Left = 30
                .Top = 100
                .Height = 750
                .Width = 680

                ' centering/resizing gets trickier
                ' but is still possible.
                ' Exercise for the reader?
                ' Hint:
                ' ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth and .SlideHeight
                ' tells you the width and height of the slide
                '
                ' All values are in Points (72 to the inch)

                End If
            End With
        Next    ' Shape
    Next osld   ' Slide

End Sub}
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `SlideIndex` property of the slides - if it is `1`, you skip to the next slide.

Just inside the `For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides` loop, add an if statement:

```
If osld.SlideIndex > 1 Then
    'Your code...
    For Each oSh In osld.Shapes
    ...
    Next    ' Shape
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Olle's correct.  Or another approach, my changes in **BOLD**:

```
Sub SlideLoop()
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
```

**Dim x as Long**

```
'For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
```

**For x = 2 to ActivePresentation.Slides.Count**

**Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)**

```
    ' check each shape on the slide
    ' is it an image or whatever you're looking for?
    For Each oSh In osld.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .Type = msoLinkedPicture _
            Or .Type = msoPicture Then

            ' position it to taste
            .Left = 30
            .Top = 100
            .Height = 750
            .Width = 680

            ' centering/resizing gets trickier
            ' but is still possible.
            ' Exercise for the reader?
            ' Hint:
            ' ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth and .SlideHeight
            ' tells you the width and height of the slide
            '
            ' All values are in Points (72 to the inch)

            End If
        End With
    Next    ' Shape
Next osld   ' Slide

End Sub
```